# Incorrect SQL Syntax when using JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In my DB I have 2 Tables. One for user Login information and one for general information.

Im trying to write a query that will select the column "firstname" from rows where the FK "users_id" is the same as the logged in users ID.

Before doing anything in PHP Im running the query in my database, so the logged in users ID, which would normally be a variable, is replaced with the id of my testuser.

This is my query:

```
SELECT b6vjp_user_info.firstname 
          FROM b6vjp_user_info 
          WHERE b6vjp_user_info.users_id LIKE 243
          INNER JOIN b6vjp_users ON b6vjp_user_info.users_id=b6vjp_users.id;
```

And here is my (censored for security reasons) Login Table named "b6vjp_users":

[image]

And here is my other table named "b6vjp_user_info":

[image]

The error is:

```
#1064 - Mistake in SQL-Syntax. 'INNER JOIN b6vjp_users ON b6vjp_user_info.users_id=b6vjp_users.id LIMIT 0, 25' on row 4
```

Now fyi I translated that, because my work environment is in german. But im sure you know what a Syntax-Error is.

Anyways I checked the JOIN Part of my query over and over again and looked up the JOIN tutorial on W3Schools. But there is no **apparent** mistake.

Does anybody see what I somehow fail to?

Comment: Put the WHERE clause after the (last) ON clause.

Comment: @jarlh Oh god such a simple mistake. Do you want to do the answer so I can mark it as solved? Need to wait 3 days when doing my own answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `WHERE` clause after the (last) `ON` clause.

Comment: I can accept the answer in 12 Minutes :) Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

you have to put `where` after `on` clause

```
  SELECT b6vjp_user_info.firstname 
              FROM b6vjp_user_info                   
              INNER JOIN 
              b6vjp_users ON  
              b6vjp_user_info.users_id=b6vjp_users.id
              WHERE b6vjp_user_info.users_id =243 // i think it int field so no need to use like operator
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using table aliases.  You also need to fix the order of your SQL clauses.  So:

```
SELECT ui.firstname 
FROM b6vjp_user_info ui JOIN
     b6vjp_users u
     ON ui.users_id = u.id
WHERE ui.users_id = '243';
```

Or, more simply without the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT ui.firstname 
FROM b6vjp_user_info ui 
WHERE ui.users_id = '243';
```

Notes:

- The operand to `LIKE` should be a string.  So, make it a string!  Implicit type conversion causes all sorts of problems.
- If you are not using wildcards, I think `=` is more informative.  If `users_id` is really a number, then just use `= 243` rather than `LIKE`.
- `WHERE` goes after the `FROM` clause.  `JOIN` is an *operator* in the `FROM` clause.
- The `JOIN` is not necessary.  Unless you are fetching columns from the users table (or need it for filtering which is highly doubtful), don't bother with it.

Comment: Wow thanks! This write up was very informative! Ill make sure to try integrating all of this into my coding :)